# Adding patch (diff) to the latest revision in pysvn

Tags: python, pysvn

I have latest revision of a folder (say 'test_project/') from svn and added locally modified changes to multiple files. Then I got the diff of locally modified changes from svn and stored in diff.txt.

Now I want to apply this changes (diff.txt) into updated/latest revision of folder in another server through pysvn. Is there any method available to do the same?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `pysvn.Client().patch()` function. It is fully documented here:

http://pysvn.tigris.org/docs/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_patch

Comment: Being the author of pysvn I'd love to know why its voted down.